# Multiple drop-down menus are all linking back to one

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm a complete beginner at HTML, CSS, and JS, so forgive me.
Right now this is what I have (sorry for the length and mess):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.ex1 {
margin: auto;
border: 0px solid transparent;
background-color: transparent;
outline: 0px solid black;
outline-offset: 0px;
width: 800px;
height:
} 

div.ex2 {
margin: auto;
border: 0px solid transparent;
background-color: transparent;
outline: 1px dashed #1e58b4;
outline-offset: 25px;
width:680px;
height:
} 

div.ex3 {
margin: auto;
border: 0px solid transparent;
background-color: transparent;
outline: 0px dashed #1e58b4;
outline-offset: 25px;
width:730px;
height:
} 
</style>
</head>

<style>
.dropbtn {
background-color: #2b89c6;
color: white;
padding: 4px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
background-color: #2b89c6;
}

.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
min-width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
font-size: 12px;    
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

.show {display:block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
  }
  }
  }
  </script>

  </body>


  <body>
  <font face="courier">
  <br>
  <div class="ex1"><font color="black"><center><font size="2.5pt">============================================================================================<br><font size="6.5pt"><big><font color="#1e58b4">Header Header Header</font></big></font></font></font><br><font color="black"><center><font size="2.5pt">============================================================================================<!--SCIENCE--></font></font><br><div class="dropdown"><button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><font face="courier">&emsp;Science&emsp;</font></button><div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content"><a href="#">Link 1</a> <a href="#">Link 2</a> <a href="#">Link 3</a> </div></div> <!--ENGLISH--><div class="dropdown"><button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><font face="courier">&emsp;English&emsp;</font></button><div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content"><a href="#">Link 1</a> <a href="#">Link 2</a> <a href="#">Link 3</a> </div></div> <!--GEOGRAPHY--><div class="dropdown"><button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><font face="courier">&emsp;Geography&emsp;</font></button><div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content"><a href="#">Link 1</a> <a href="#">Link 2</a> <a href="#">Link 3</a> </div></div> <!--BUSINESS--><div class="dropdown"><button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><font face="courier">&emsp;Business&emsp;</font></button><div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content"><a href="#">Link 1</a> <a href="#">Link 2</a> <a href="#">Link 3</a> </div></div> <!--FRENCH--><div class="dropdown"><button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><font face="courier">&emsp;French&emsp;</font></button><div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content"><a href="#">Link 1</a> <a href="#">Link 2</a> <a href="#">Link 3</a> </div></div> <!--MUSIC--><div class="dropdown"><button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><font face="courier">&emsp;Music&emsp;</font></button><div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content"><a href="#">Link 1</a> <a href="#">Link 2</a> <a href="#">Link 3</a> </div> </div><br><font  size="2.5pt">============================================================================================</font></div>
<br>
</font>
```

When any of the menus are clicked, only the first dropdown comes up. I know there's probably easier ways to do this, but I'd like the appearance to stay exactly as it.

If anyone could show me a fix for this, that'd be beyond helpful.
Thank You!

Comment: You should start by fixing your HTML. `<font>` and `<center>` are no longer valid tags. Do your styling in CSS. Next, please format your code with indentation and remove excessive blank lines so it is readable.

Comment: Note: The 'ID' of an element is supposed to be unique per node in the DOM. This will cause issues in behavior if you continue giving multiple nodes the same ID. I will take a look at your issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your whole document needs revamping to be more up to date in terms of standards and also to make things easier in making it work.

Based on your current document;

Change all of you dropdown divs to be as so.

```
<div class="dropdown" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <button  class="dropbtn">&emsp;Science&emsp;</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content"><a href="#">Link 1</a> <a href="#">Link 2</a> <a href="#">Link 3</a> </div>
</div>
```

Change your javascript to be as so;

```
<script>
function myFunction(element) {
  // Here I am assuming the dropdown div to have the same child 
  // elements in the same order each block
  element.children[1].classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Add `font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace` into the `.dropbtn` stylng in order to keep the font. I would advise moving all of the `font` tags to use this method. You should be using CSS for things like that.

#### Things to note;

Tags that should not really be used any more;
`<font>`, `<center>`, `<big>`. - These should all be achieved through CSS properties bound to classes and/or IDs.

`ID` should be set to a unique value for all elements that need it across the current DOM. `Class` is fine to be used multiple times across elements.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly! Thanks for being so clear, I'll start changing the deprecated tags I have everywhere else now ;)